# Row-wise Pearson correlation between two dataframes or matrices

Tags: r, caret

I want to find the mean Pearson correlation between `bval` and `kirp_expr`.

```
meth_exp_corr <- diag(cor(bval, as.numeric(kirp_expr), method="pearson"))$estimate # Row-wise correlation
```

Traceback:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diag': error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'cor': 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Data:

```
> dput(bval[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.936541813395938, 0.056245209738118, 0.0530093175522538, 
0.528332559219693, 0.200359336965341, 0.884098121190752, 0.0587209886180834, 
0.0157260359008846, 0.503125336781981, 0.147287104179572, 0.903812646370023, 
0.0485626039439297, 0.0437850437850438, 0.554738132772815, 0.134233917541305, 
0.955365812154032, 0.0407083939835032, 0.0617595436594998, 0.224848934591328, 
0.116850371010734, 0.832430340557275, 0.348511149686206, 0.650490852298081, 
0.620003210788248, 0.142329020332717), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("cg00001349", "cg00001583", "cg00002719", "cg00002837", 
    "cg00003287"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))

> dput(kirp_expr[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 = c(7.65342121905285, 14.3511850042327, 
10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255, 9.44832324553208), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(5.09389393824392, 
12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252, 9.9623840324273
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 = c(4.70168212029528, 10.1689338100564, 9.96839262629172, 
9.87305770150294, 9.75535162798678), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(5.13719199914349, 
12.0367193976262, 10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849, 9.91216810777653
), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 = c(6.95117512427229, 10.9656928148969, 10.5991523452113, 
10.4556415168452, 9.46537845450025)), row.names = c("ENSG00000121410", 
"ENSG00000175899", "ENSG00000128274", "ENSG00000291836", "ENSG00000081760"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Dimensions:

```
> dim(bval)
[1] 65737   172
> dim(kirp_expr)
[1] 11537   172
```

Comment: Does this  `meth_exp_corr <- diag(cor(bval, kirp_expr, method="pearson"))` works?

Comment: No, I still get an error

Comment: Please check the class of x and y in your input:  `class(bval)` is giving me [1] "matrix" "array", and  `class(kirp_expr)`gives [1] "data.frame" and everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `as.numeric` on a `data.frame`.

```r
as.numeric(iris)
#> Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Instead, you need to convert `kirp_expr` to a `matrix`.

```r
diag(cor(bval, as.matrix(kirp_expr), method="pearson"))
#> TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 
#>      -0.7199122      -0.9051944      -0.8452573      -0.9731041      -0.4481620
```

However, this only works because the number of rows in your two example objects are the same. You will get an "incompatible dimensions" error if you try this on your real data. What do you *mean* by correlation if you have different numbers of rows?

Comment: I think I meant row-wise correlation, probably transposing might work